# Calling a gRPC call after one returns from the server side

Tags: c++, grpc

I have these two gRPC calls:

```
service Console {
  rpc JoinNetwork(keyvaluestore.Request) returns (ClusterInfo) {}
  rpc WatchHealth(HealthCheckRequest) returns (stream HealthCheckResponse) {}
}
```

Which are used by two entities: a masternode and a storage node. When a storage node first starts up, it calls `JoinNetwork()` to the masternode, which returns some information to the storage node.

I then want to call `WatchHealth()` from the masternode, which pings the storage node, which in returns continually sends a "heartbeat" message in perpetuity to the server until it crashes.

The only way I can think of chaining these two calls together is calling WatchHealth inside the server implementation of JoinNetwork. But I really only want to call WatchHealth **after** JoinNetwork returns, which I'm not sure how to do.

**JoinNetwork (client):**

```
bool ConsoleClient::JoinNetwork(const string& my_addr, ClusterInfo* cinfo) {
  ClientContext ctx;
  Request req;
  Status status = stub_->JoinNetwork(&ctx, req, cinfo);
  if (status.ok()) {
    log("[C: JoinNetwork] Successfully joined cluster " + to_string(cinfo->cid()), VB);
    return true;
  } else {
    log("[C: JoinNetwork] Error " + to_string(status.error_code()) + ": " + status.error_message(), VB);
    return false;
  }
}
```

**JoinNetwork (server):**

```
Status ConsoleServiceImpl::JoinNetwork(ServerContext* ctx, const Request* req, ClusterInfo* res) {
  MLOCK.lock();
  int cid = (NUM_NODES++) % K;
  CDIR[cid].insert(req->addr());
  if (CPRIMES.find(cid) == CPRIMES.end()) {
    CPRIMES.insert({ cid, req->addr() }); // If no primary exists, make it the primary
  }
  res->set_cid(cid);
  res->set_sid(assign_sid(cid));
  res->set_caddrs(pack_addrs(CDIR[cid]));
  res->set_primary(CPRIMES[cid]);
  log("[S: JoinNetwork] Storage node " + req->addr() + " has joined cluster " + to_string(cid), VB);
  MLOCK.unlock();

  return Status::OK;
}
```

**WatchHealth (client):**

```
bool ConsoleClient::WatchHealth(const string& addr) {
  ClientContext ctx;
  auto deadline = chrono::system_clock::now() + chrono::milliseconds(500);
  ctx.set_deadline(deadline);
  HealthCheckRequest req;
  HealthCheckResponse res;
  unique_ptr<ClientReader<HealthCheckResponse>> reader(stub_->WatchHealth(&ctx, req));
  while (reader->Read(&res));
  Status status = reader->Finish();
  if (status.ok()) {
    log("[C: WatchHealth] Storage node " + addr + " shutdown gracefully", VB);
    return true;
  } else {
    log("[C: WatchHealth] Storage node " + addr + " crashed", VB);
    return false;
  }
}
```

**WatchHealth (server):**

```
Status ConsoleServiceImpl::WatchHealth(ServerContext* ctx, const HealthCheckRequest* req, ServerWriter<HealthCheckResponse>* writer) {
  HealthCheckResponse res;
  while (true) {
    res.set_status(console::HealthCheckResponse::SERVING);
    writer->Write(res);
  }
  res.set_status(console::HealthCheckResponse::SHUTTING_DOWN);
  writer->Write(res);
  return Status::OK;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't `JoinNetwork()` and `WatchHealth()` be on separate nodes? Because if I understand your use case; the storage calls the master (in which case the master is the server of the request) and then the master watches the storage HB (in which case storage serves the HB)

Comment: Yes precisely, did I design the gRPC wrong?

Comment: Yes I believe so. Master should have `service Console { rpc Join(...)  returns (...)} ` and the Storage should have `service HealthCheck { rpc WatchHealth(...) returns (stream ...)}`.

Comment: I see. Do u have any suggestions for my current problem though?